# Print struct member

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
};

int main() {
    Person a;
    a.first_name = "foo";
    a.last_name = "bar";
    cout << a.first_name << " " << a.last_name;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives error:

```
binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of
type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: You're missing to `#include <string>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you need to include `string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Person {
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
};

int main() {
    Person a;
    a.first_name = "foo";
    a.last_name = "bar";
    cout << a.first_name << " " << a.last_name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I understood that I needed to include it, but why? string is available without including <string>.

Comment: @karaxuna No it isn't, there's just a forward declaration in `<iostream>`.